# Finding c in Taylor approximation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f (x)=\sin^2 (x) $ if this function is approximated by first two non zero terms then what should be $c $ so that $\text {Error} \leq 0.005$ . Now I know the second non zero term is $4th $ derivative of $f (x) $  so $n=4$ degree polynomial hence max error =$_{max [0,c]}\frac {|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} _{max [0,c]}|16\sin (2c)|\leq 0.005. $ now how to continue from here? As we dont know where $2c $ is max.

Comment: The range is $0 <x <c $ nothing else is given so I am a bit confused about how to get $c$.

Comment: So that means $c=\frac {\pi}{4} $ hence max error is $\frac{(\frac {\pi}{4})^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $